# built-in dictionary in Samsung note 8

Tags: android, ipad

I am about to buy a tablet and I am between ipad mini and samsung note 8!
I found interesting the build-in dictionary in ipad (which gives the definition of any word in any app) and I would like to ask if there is something similar in samsung.

Thanks!

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, this should be on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

No.  In Android this is either the responsibility of the InputManager (keyboard) or the SpellCheckSession.  But Samsung disables the SpellCheckSession an doesn't allow you to access it (and truthfully, it doesn't work well anyway, as it isn't tied in well in an architecture where you can change keyboards).